# Issue creating Windows NTFS directory junction in C/C++

Tags: c++, .net, c, visual-studio-2013, ntfs

I am trying to do this using Visual C++. This code seems to create a junction, with the correct target set, but the junction has a size of 0 and when I click on it I get:

[image: error message]

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct _REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER {
    ULONG  ReparseTag;
    USHORT  ReparseDataLength;
    USHORT  Reserved;
    union {
        struct {
            USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
            USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
            USHORT PrintNameOffset;
            USHORT PrintNameLength;
            ULONG Flags;
            WCHAR PathBuffer[1];
        } SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
        struct {
            USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
            USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
            USHORT PrintNameOffset;
            USHORT PrintNameLength;
            WCHAR PathBuffer[1];
        } MountPointReparseBuffer;
        struct {
            UCHAR DataBuffer[1];
        } GenericReparseBuffer;
    };
} REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;

#define REPARSE_MOUNTPOINT_HEADER_SIZE 8

bool createJunction(WCHAR *linkPath, WCHAR *newTargetPath) {
    int create_status = CreateDirectory(linkPath, NULL);

    // If the directory already existed, treat it as a success.
    if (create_status == 0 && (GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS || (GetFileAttributesW(linkPath) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0))
        return false;

    HANDLE handle = CreateFile(linkPath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Could not open dir '%s'; error: %d\n"), linkPath, GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(handle);
        return false;
    }

    int target_len = wcslen(newTargetPath);
    if (target_len > MAX_PATH - 1) {
        CloseHandle(handle);
        return false;
    }

    int reparse_data_buffer_size = sizeof REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER + 2 * MAX_PATH * sizeof WCHAR;
    REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* reparse_data_buffer = static_cast<REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*>(calloc(reparse_data_buffer_size, 1));

    reparse_data_buffer->ReparseTag = IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT;
    wcscpy(reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer, newTargetPath);
    wcscpy(reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer + target_len + 1, newTargetPath);
    reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset = 0;
    reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength = target_len * sizeof(WCHAR);
    reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset = (target_len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    reparse_data_buffer->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength = target_len * sizeof(WCHAR);
    reparse_data_buffer->ReparseDataLength = (target_len + 1) * 2 * sizeof(WCHAR) + REPARSE_MOUNTPOINT_HEADER_SIZE;

    DWORD dummy_received_bytes;
    int result = DeviceIoControl(
        handle,
        FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT,
        reparse_data_buffer,
        reparse_data_buffer->ReparseDataLength + REPARSE_MOUNTPOINT_HEADER_SIZE,
        NULL,
        0,
        &dummy_received_bytes,
        NULL);
    if (CloseHandle(handle) == 0)
        return false;
    free(reparse_data_buffer);

    return (result != 0);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    createJunction(L"C:\\Users\\Weston\\Desktop\\New folder\\Junction of asdf", L"C:\\Users\\Weston\\Desktop\\New folder\\asdf");

    _tprintf(_T("Execution complete.\n"));
    getchar();
}
```

I am almost sure I am not setting the size correctly somewhere, but no sure what and where. There are no errors or warnings, the junction simply seems to be created (with the correct name and target and type of junction) with a size of 0.

Comment: The MSDN page has comments indicating, among other things, that "A junction/mountpoint path should start with "\??\"  (SC_Win32ReparsePrefix)
 and refer to a volume known on the local system. Otherwise error
 ERROR_INVALID_REPARSE_DATA is returned. The path may contain a drive letter
 or a volume guid, followed by a subdirectory."

Comment: Prefixing the target with this, but now the junction seems to link to itself rather than the target, although the target appears correct in the properties. I guess I'm not doing it right :\

Comment: Hold on I found what I was doing wrong. Go ahead and post that as the answer.

Comment: Here is an example https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git/+/d2a3a8029e10ee9e07505f735af931bab616afaa/create-ntfs-junction.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not prefixing target path with `\??\`. Doing so was all I needed to do.